# How to give space between words using regex

Tags: regex-group, automation-testing

For ex: I have elements as below:

1.MyFirstword is java

where I need to output as My First word is java

Can we get this using regex exp to give space between words

Comment: based on what logic they should be splitted ?

Comment: I need to split the sentence as per words. My expected output is "My First word is java" but while extracting the word I am getting "MyFirstword is java" so expected and actual is not matching.